# How to add an CAShapeLayer to a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have this error when I try to add an CAShaperLayer to my NSDictionary:

```
[<__NSDictionaryI 0x7fafe4826d70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key layer.
```

and here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *pixelDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[pixelDictionary setValue:pixelLayer forKey:@"layer"];
```

I tried to search around [NSValue valueWith...] but there is no method for CAShapeLayer...

So, how to add an CAShapeLayer to a NSDictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASharperLayer is an object, and there isn´t any problem to put inside a dict. 
Your problem is: You can use a inmutable dict, in this case put in the moment you create it:

```
   NSDictionary *pixelDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:pixelLayer,@"layer", nil];
```

Or use a mutable dict:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *pixelMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[pixelDictionary setValue:pixelLayer forKey:@"layer"];
```